# NGXS @Action method not invoking

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I have angular app where I'm trying to integrate `ngxs`. The problem is that when I dispatch action from the component, state method which listens to a particular action, not being invoked.

My `core.module.ts` looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    NgxsModule.forRoot([RoomPropertiesState], ngxsConfig),
    NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsDispatchPluginModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor(
    @Optional()
    @SkipSelf()
    parent: CoreModule
  ) {
    if (parent) {
      throw new Error('Module already included!');
    }
  }
}
```

and `room-properties.state.ts` :

```
@State<RoomPropertiesStateModel>({
  name: 'roomproperties',
  defaults: {
    isLoading: false,
    totalCount: 0,
    allRoomProperties: [],
  },
})
@Injectable()
export class RoomPropertiesState implements NgxsOnInit {
  constructor(
    private configurationService: ConfigurationService
  ) {
    debugger;
  }

  ngxsOnInit(ctx: StateContext<RoomPropertiesStateModel>): void {
    debugger;
  }

  @Action(Actions.LoadRoomProperties)
  loadRoomProperties(ctx: StateContext<RoomPropertiesStateModel>): void {
    debugger;
    ctx.setState(startLoading());
  }
}
```

and finally component:

```
export class RoomPropertiesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private configurationService: ConfigurationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.loadRoomProperties();
  }

  @Dispatch()
  private loadRoomProperties(): LoadRoomProperties {
    return new LoadRoomProperties({ sorting: '', skipCount: 0, maxResultCount: 10 });
  }
}
```

when component dispatches the action, no debugger is hit in the `room-properties.state.ts`

Comment: Are your other debugger statements being hit? ie the constructor and ngxsOnInit?

Comment: @Richard.Davenport nope

Comment: Also, can you show what your action class looks like?

Comment: Here's my action class:
export class LoadRoomProperties {
  static readonly type = '[Room Properties] Load All';
  constructor(
    public payload: { sorting: string, skipCount: number, maxResultCount: number }
  ) {}
}

Comment: Sounds like an ng module issue, can you temporarily import into your app module and not your core module?

Comment: @Richard.Davenport Let me try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225642/discussion-between-richard-davenport-and-arkadi).